# Cryptology Proof

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

> Given prime $p, 0 < m < p$ and $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1}$, prove $ m^{ed} \equiv m \pmod{p}$.

I get that this is hinting at a proof very similar to that of RSA, and that I have to consider when $\gcd(m,p)=1$ and when it doesn't. I also know that I need to use Euler's theorem and CRT. I just can't get past the $p-1$ passing itself into the mod from Euler's theorem. How should this proof look?

Comment: Your question will be better recieved if you write down your proof or at least parts of it and ask specific questions about it.

Comment: Euler’s Theorem tells you that $x^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ when $\gcd(x,n)=1$. If $\gcd(x,n)=1$, and $r\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$, then $r=1+k\varphi{n}$ for some integer $k$, so $x^{r} = x^{1+k\varphi(n)} = x^1x^{k\varphi(n)} = x(x^{\varphi(n)})^k$. What does this equal modulo $n$? And what is $\varphi(n)$ when $n$ is a prime?

Comment: First question : m mod n as the proof requests.  But don't I have r = 1 mod (p-1)? And idk when n is prime. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: I do not understand *anything* of what you wrote. You say “first question”, but what follows is not a question, it’s a sentence fragment. Don’t confuse the letters I wrote with the letters in your original problem. I’m using $n$ and $x$ as arbitrary letters, not related to your problem statement.  Did you understand what *I* wrote? And do you **really** don’t know the value of Euler’s phi function when the input is a prime? If that is the case, then sorry, but you are too far behind to tackle *this* problem. You need to go way back and actually learn the stuff first.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay I meant the phi function of p when p is prime is p-1. But idk where to go with that. You did the proof for when gcd(x,n) = 1 but Idk what to do when it isn't/

Comment: Look at your problem. $p$ is a prime. $m$ is a positive integer **smaller** than the prime. What is the gcd of $m$ with $p$?

Comment: oh lol it's always one right?

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me?

Comment: Telling because factors of a prime are one and itself and if the number is less than the prime in order for the gcd not to be one the number would have to be a factor of the prime which it cant be by the definition of a prime.

Comment: So, presumably, you’ve got your hints and hnnow how to solve the problem. Great. May I suggest posting your final solution as an answer? That way the question won’t go “unanswered”, and other people can help and point out any gaps or errors.

Answer (score 1):

First consider gcd(m,p). p is prime and p > m.

Conclude gcd(m,p) = 1.

By Euler's Theorem 
$ 
m^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \mod p, 
ed \equiv 1 \mod \phi(p), ed \equiv 1 +k\phi(p),k$ is a constant integer and then $(m^{e})^d = m^{ed} \equiv m^{1+k\phi(p)}\\ \\ m^{ed} \equiv m *m^{k\phi(p)}\\m^{ed} \equiv m *1\mod p\\m^{ed} \equiv m \mod p$

Comment: Use `\pmod` to get the proper notation and spacing, not `\mod`.Look at the edits I did to your question to see the sytax and formatting.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. You *do* need to consider it; it’s just that it is equal to 1. And therefore, you do not **suppose** that $\gcd(m,p)=1$. You *conclude* that it is one because $p$ is prime and $m$ is positive and strictly smaller. You never say what $k$ is (not any constant will make this work, it has to be a *specific* constant). Your second line is wrong (where did that addition symbol come from?)

Comment: Thanks, better? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: $P$ and $p$ will be understood to mean different things, so you shouldn’t use them interchangeably. (If that was your interface automatically changing it to an upper case because if tollows a period, ignore that comment). You still never say what $k$ is or why it matters, and you still have a plus sign that doesn’t make any sense in your second equation.

Comment: Yeah p was automatically capitalized sorry about that. Fixed the plus sign, not sure what k is missing.

Comment: In line 3 you say, “$k$ is a constant integer”. But you never defined $k$ as something specific, so right now it’s just an arbitrary integer. But if it is an arbitrary integer, then why do you claim that $m^{ed}\equiv m^{1+k\phi(p)}$? Since you did not specify the integer $k$, you are asserting that this holds for *any* positive integer $k$. So if I plug in $k=3$, it’s true; if I plug in $k=73$ it’s true. If I plug in $k=4128973126321236$, it’s true. Or at least, that’s what you are claiming happens. Does it?  (And, congruent modulo what?)

Comment: I think they want you to say that the existence of a k is implied by the previous modulus (and moreover that it doesn't work for just any k).

Comment: I know you have to work mod phi (p) in the exponent but beyond that I'm not sure. K >= 1? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @Christheyankee: Re-read my original comment and try to follow the substance; don’t just try to emulate the form. In particular, there was a $k$ I used, but it wasn’t just *any* $k$; it was a $k$ whose existence and properties were implied by another assumption I had.

Comment: Did I add the assumption correctly? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: You might want to say that $ ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(p)}$ implies the existence of an integer k such that $ed = 1 + k \phi(n)$

Comment: @Christheyankee: You did not add any assumption, so.. no. Look at Boots comment. Look at my original comment. Where did $k$ come from, and what properties did it have? They are key. You are just ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

It's a special case of this [mod exponent reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) law (crucial to *master* for problems like this)

**Lemma** $\ \bmod n\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large k}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large j\bmod\color{#c00} k}$

**Proof** $\ $ Dividing $\ j\div k\,\Rightarrow\, j = r + k\,q\ $ for $\ r = j\bmod k = $ remainder, and $\,q = $ quotient,

hence $\bmod n\!:\,\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large r+kq}\equiv a^{\large r}(\color{#c00}{a^{\large k}})^{\large q}\equiv a^{\large r}\color{#c00}1^{\large q}\equiv a^{\large r}$

---

Thus $\bmod p\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{m^{\large p-1}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, m^{\large ed}\equiv m^{\large ed\bmod\color{#c00}{p-1}}\equiv m^{\large 1}$